# Binary Formatter - Type UserControl is not marked as serializable

Tags: c#, serialization

I'm trying to serialize my object using `BinaryFormatter`:

```
private UserSettings _userSettings;
var serializer = new BinaryFormatter();
using (var file = new FileStream(@"D:\test.bin", FileMode.Create))
{
    serializer.Serialize(file, _userSettings);
}
```

But I'm getting a strange exception:

> Type 'MyCustomUserControl' in Assembly 'xxx' is not marked as
>   serializable.

Class `UserSettings` doesn't have any reference to `MyCustomUserControl` but it's referenced by `MyCustomUserControl`.

Comment: Have you used `[Serializable]` for your CustomUserControl?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reference to the control can be hidden in an event. If your `UserSettings` class implements an event to which the control is subscribed, add the `[field:NonSerialized]` attribute to the event:

```
[field:NonSerialized]
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

Answer (score 1):

For using `BinaryFormatter`serializer, your class **needs to be** marked as `Serializable`. Here is an example:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyCustomUserControl: Control
{
    // 
}
```

Comment: You can also manually implement ISerializable to solve this if you need fine grained control over the serialization process.

Comment: @Kevin Thanks for mention it.

Comment: wouldnt it be `[Serializable()]` not `[Serializable]`

Comment: @peterpep it's not necessary to write parentheses. You can even write like `SerializableAttribute()` but `[Serializable]` is enough.

Comment: [Serializable] works but my problem was that the reference to the control was hidden in an event.