# How to find field that prevents serialization in a large assembly?

Tags: c#, serialization

I am trying to implement serialization for a class `ClassToBeSerialized` in a large assembly `AssemblyOne`. I use the binary formatter. I get the error

> SystemError: Type 'HugeClass' in Assembly 'AssemblyTwo' is not marked as serializable.

The `HugeClass` should not be serialized, so I'd like to prevent that by using the `[NonSerialized]` attribute. However, I don't know how to find the field that refers to this class. `ClassToBeSerialized` does not directly refer to `HugeClass`, nor does any other class of `AssemblyOne`. Probably it is an event or something else that is declared at run time, which makes the connection. It might be a field in a field in a field ..., so there is little chance to manually trace the connection.

Can you think of a way how to automatically resolve the path of fields that finally refer to `HugeClass`?

Edit: The question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40913641/8028981).

Comment: If you can't find any connection then try to look for superclasses of `HugeClass` used in `AssemblyOne`. For example an array of `object`

Comment: I would strongly recommend against using BinaryFormatter. It is insecure, slow, inefficient, poor backwards compatibility and obsoleted in newer .net versions. There are various better alternatives for serialization.

Comment: @JonasH Is there a solution that you can particularly recommend?

Comment: I have used protobuf.net, xml & json, and any of them work well, even if xml is mostly replaced by json. But it depend on your requirements. See [software recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) for recommendations.